# Python: argparse.ArgumentParser() - overriding global defaults

Tags: python, argparse

I have a case where a program does 3 tasks, which has corresponding 3 *optional* arguments.
If **none** of the 3 arguments are passed, then **do all 3 tasks**.
But if any of arguments are specifically mentioned, then do only those task !

After going through the docs, I have come up with a solution, but feel it is not shortest or efficient way to do so.

In the `argparse` document, I used `store_false` to achieve it

```
my_parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_false')
my_parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_false')
my_parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_false')
```

But then I have to use the below logic to achieve my requirement.
Say if argument for task `a` and `c` are specified. So, we shouldn't do task `b`

```
a = False
b = True
c = False

l = [a,b,c]

if all(l):
    print("Do All 3 tasks")
else:
    if not a:
        print('Do task A ')
    if not b:
        print('Do task B')
    if not c:
        print('Do task C')
```

```
> python3 arg_check.py 
Do task A 
Do task C
```

But this a lot code i believe?

Is there any better way within the `argparse` library, that overrides the value of other arguments based on any other arguments ?

Comment: I don't see argparse related code in your question, you need to add it

Comment: Nothing wrong with a few `if` statements.  `argparse` should be seen primarily as a parsing tool - what does the user want.  Streamlined execution from that input is secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of specifying 3 different arguments, you can use one which takes a varying number of values. You can then set the default for all tasks, and conveniently this argument will be a list so you can just iterate it. Something like:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('tasks', nargs='*', default=['a', 'b', 'c'])
args = parser.parse_args()
for task in args.tasks:
    print(task, end=' ')
```

Run examples:

```
>>> arg_check.py
a b c 
>>> arg_check.py a c
a c
```

Answer (score 0):

Set default to ""(empty string) and set choices to ['A', 'B', 'C'], also set action to 'store_true'. Check which one among them is set. You can get which is set by checking args.'optional_argument_name' and do that particular task. If the optional argument is set to "" you can do a task for it. Also set nagrs to "*" which means it takes 0 or more arguments.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('simple-check')
parser.add_argument(
    "-c","--check",
    help="select from choices",
    choices=['A','B','C'],
    nargs="*",
    action="store_true",
    default=""
) 

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.check == "":
    # do a task
elif args.check == "A":
    # do a task
elif args.check == "B":
    # do a task
elif args.check == "C":
    # do a task
```